# Proof Verification: Show that $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2\sin(xy)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

The function is defined such that at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ we have that $f(x,y)=0$. And so I was trying to prove that $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{x^2\sin(xy)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0$ and am not sure whether my bound is correct, would appreciate some feedback on the proof.

Proof:

Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Let $\delta=\epsilon^{\frac{1}{3}}$ such that when $\vec{x}=(x,y)\in{}D$ and $0<||\vec{x}-\vec{0}||<\delta$ we have,
\begin{equation}
\left|\frac{x^2\sin(xy)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-0\right|=\frac{|x^2\sin(xy)|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{|x^2xy\cdot\sin(xy)|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot{}xy}
\end{equation}

Whereas $\frac{\sin(xy)}{xy}\rightarrow1$ as $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$ and hence it leaves us with,

\begin{equation}
\frac{|x^3y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{|x|^3|y|}{||\vec{x}||}\leq\frac{||\vec{x}||^3||\vec{x}||}{||\vec{x}||}=||\vec{x}||^3<\delta^3=\epsilon.
\end{equation}

How does this look?

Comment: $\frac{sinx}{x}$ does not go to zero as x goes to zero

Comment: Sorry I meant it goes to 1

Comment: Looks good (except the $\frac{\sin x}{x}\to 0$, I suppose it's a typo). Notice that (to make easier) $$|\frac{x^2\sin(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|\leq \frac{|x|^2}{\|x\|}\leq \|x\|\to 0,$$ But what you did is very good as well.

Comment: Yeah see that's the thing I was wondering about earlier, in one variable I would just say $|\sin(x)|\leq{}1$ and thus we instantly get to our point but I was a bit hesitant doing it over here for some reason, even though it does sound trivial. Thanks for making that clear.